# Change MediaWiki's default language strings

Tags: mediawiki

I am learning MediaWiki 1.31.1 and hope to change default interface strings. For example, out-of-the-box signup page displays this:

```
Email address (optional)
```

I would like to show (remove optional)

```
Email address
```

I am able to hack the MediaWiki string file (/languages/i18n/en.json) and make changes there. Any better way?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a multilingual wiki, or if your users are likely to use different interface languages (such as when using the Universal Language Selector extension to automatically use visitor's preferred language), then you should use the [MessageCache::get](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/MessageCache::get) hook so that the customization is used in all languages. Otherwise user's using a different interface language will not see the customization.

It's used like this:

LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgHooks['MessageCache::get'][] = function ( &$key ) {
    $keys = [ // The list of messages you want to customize
            'prefs-help-realname',
            'createacct-realname',
    ];

    if ( in_array( $key, $keys, true ) ) {
            $key = "myprefix-$key";
    }
};
```

Then you need to edit `https://example.org/wiki/MediaWiki:myprefix-key` (replace with your wiki domain and *key* with the original message key (which you can find with `uselang=qqx`).

Answer (score 2):

Append `uselang=qqx` to the URL to see message names instead of the text of the messages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CreateAccount?uselang=qqx

You should only see the `(optional)` part though if you [configured email to be optional](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgEmailConfirmToEdit), so I'm not sure the message text is your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any language string can also be edited by going to the page MediaWiki:name-of-language-string on your wiki and editing that.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am a bit confused. You mean this page `/index.php/En`? I suppose these strings should be in one resource file.

Comment: Here is an example from the popular Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Action-createtalk is the page that is used to edit the `action-createtalk` language string.